# How to add sitemap to my Blogspot blog?

Tags: sitemap, blogger, blogspot

I added a lot of pages in my blog. I need to track the blog traffic.

If anyone know about adding sitemap to my blog, please send step by step tutorial for this process.

Comment: Do you know how to generate sitemap, and what are sitemaps for?

Comment: I am not really sure about your problem, because when I enter your question "adding sitemap blogspot" in google I get like over 9000 tutorials. including youtube videos. Do you have some problems with them?

Comment: Blogspot may indeed have specific steps or requirements. I have no idea. However, it is often not necessary to add a sitemap. Sitemaps do not help with SEO. In fact, they are mostly only used to audit whether a search engine can effectively crawl your site. Use a sitemap if your site is extremely large or has a paywall of login before content. Other than that, my assumption is that a sitemap is not needed. My assumption is that any Blogspot site should be easily crawled and therefore search engines would prefer crawling over using a sitemap.

Comment: @veritaS, Yes, i able to see lot of tutorials for adding sitemap to the blogspot. This tutorial provides option to generate sitemap with post link.
In my blog, i have used lot of page templates instead of posts. So i need to generate sitemap with pages instead of posts.

Answer (score 3):

1. Sign in to [Google Webmaster Tools](http://www.google.com/webmasters/).
2. Click on the blog title for which you want to add sitemap.
3. Click on Sitemaps button.
4. At the top right corner of the page, press Add/Test sitemap button.
5. Once you click the button, a small box will appear.
6. Add the below code in the text field.

> atom.xml?redirect=false&start-index=1&max-results=500

This is the sitemap code for your blogger blog which you need to add. The number 500 refers to how many posts you want fetched.

7. Press “Submit Sitemap” button.

Refresh the page and you're done.

Comment: Google [generate sitemap automatically](https://www.goyllo.com/blogger/seo/xml-sitemap/) just go to the `www.yourblog.blogspot.com/sitemap.xml` and `www.yourblog.blogspot.com/sitemap-pages.xml`