# How to create a custom sitemap file without sitemap generator?

Tags: sitemap, website-design, cms

I want to create a sitemap file without the sitemap generator. That is a sitemap file with urls we manually add. I will edit sitemap each time when i add new page. So how to do this and use with my website.

Comment: See the following Google help doc:  [Build and submit a sitemap](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/183668?hl=en).

Comment: @dan, can i upload sitemap in dropbox because i don't have a hosting.

Comment: Why would you need a sitemap if you don't have hosting? Normally you'd place the sitemap in the root directory of your site, or specify the location in your [robots.txt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots_exclusion_standard#Sitemap). They need to be publicly available regardless.

Comment: @dan, i am using blogspot.

Comment: I had thought Blogger started creating them automatically for its users. You can however create one and upload it using Search Console (Webmaster Tools) - see [this](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/96421/how-to-add-sitemap-to-my-blogspot-blog) answer as to how.

Comment: David Why you don't mention you;re using blogspot in question? [Blogger generate sitemap automatically](https://www.goyllo.com/blogger/seo/xml-sitemap/), just go to the `www.yourblog.blogspot.com/sitemap.xml`

Comment: @dan, no blogger don't create sitemap automatically. We have to use sitemap generators for this. But for this the limit of url is 500. Thats why i plan to create a sitemap by myself and upload somewhere else and gives that link. So is it possible to give direct link of sitemap which is uploaded in google drive. Will that work?

Comment: Can you please refer my above link. It generate sitemap automatically. I have used blogger since 2011. Name your blog URL and I can show you all links in your sitemap.

Comment: @Goyllo, thats a useful information. I didn't know google automatically does that. But what if i want to index image url also?

Comment: Brother, you're using Google product, they already index tons of images from many blogspot blog automatically. just find out any blog who use many pictures and search that blog on Google Image search, and you'll see all the images are index automatically. Google don't need sitemap for everything, they just crawl links from everywhere. WIkipedia does not have any sitemap but still it crawl very efficiently and their content index very fast. It's just matter of content, if it is good then Google will surely index it. But to answer your question, blogger does not have any image sitemap.

Answer (score 3):

1. Create a new document file like `file.txt` (In most OS you can do that by clicking on right button) and edit the extension from `file.txt` to `file.xml` or `sitemap.xml`, whatever you want.
2. Add your all URL's in simple line. No need to add XML sitemap tags like `<loc>` `<url>` etc. Just plain **absolute URL** name like [google use on their sitemap](https://edu.google.com/sitemap.xml)
3. Upload your sitemap on your server, it can be anywhere, there is no any strict rules like `www.example.com/my/folder/sitemap.xml` you can also use `.txt` extension as I said like `sitemap.txt`
4. If your server have cpanel, then you may have many editor to edit your file.xml, so just add your new URL anywhere (on top/bottom) and whenever you want.

P.S. please add your comment if I miss understood your question.

Comment: can this sitemap compatible with every other search engines.

Comment: Yes [bing support plain text sitemap](https://www.bing.com/webmaster/help/how-to-submit-sitemaps-82a15bd4) as well.

Comment: What if i want to index image urls also.